# MPC not visible when running from Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler, media-player-classic

I have created a task to run a song with MPC, it runs without any window, only as a task that I can see on Task Manager, MPC is being called by the task taskeng.exe

I have inserted in the script/program argument the path to the song.

How can I make mpc run visibly as a standard window that can be closed normally as opposed to windowless process?

Comment: You must use your own credentials. See https://superuser.com/questions/656964/what-user-must-a-scheduled-task-run-as-in-order-to-be-visible-for-all-users

Comment: I'm not having trouble seeing it, nor making it run as X user, I'm having trouble closing the MPC windows (song) as I am forced to run script to kill mpc or to enter task manager manually each morning after alarm :)